# VCO with range of 0.2 Hz to 27.0 Hz

Tags: oscillator, stepper-motor, vco

I have developed and built a tangentially tracking tone arm for playing LP vinyl records. Its carriage is driven by a 15 mm diameter stepping motor.
Mechanical design is easy for me, however, now I'm in need of a VCO to produce a square wave from 0.2 Hz to 27.0 Hz to drive the stepping motor driver which I bought from Sparkfun. I found a 555 timer based VCO on the internet that works but it does not give me the frequency spread mentioned above. The input to the VCO comes from the amplified output of a linear analog Hall Effect sensor.
Could someone help with the design of the required VCO?

---

Hello to all above who have responded to my question from 2013.
I am in shock because I was not aware that there had been any answers.
Thank you very much.

I have been improving the tone arm since 2013 to where the required servo has become much simpler. I will be asking questions about that in the next few days.

In 1984 I patented the idea of using a stepper motor to drive a tangential tone arm, and let me assure you that it worked flawlessly.

"Gearing" the tone arm to the rotation of the turn table platter will not work, because the grooves on an LP don't have the same pitch from groove to groove.

Sincerely,

Ralf

Comment: Honestly, I think this is a great application of Arduino (as much as I don't think it should be used as a be-all end-all device). You will be able to program the behaviour instead of using the kind of drifty/imprecise nature of non-precision analog VCOs, especially when driven from not quite linear hall effect sensors.

Comment: How precisely does the frequency need to be controlled? What is the voltage source that is to be translated to the step clock? How critical is the linearity between voltage and frequency - does it need to be linear at all?

Comment: Take the stepper signal from the turntable, so they stay in sync.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but a stepper seems like not the best choice for something like this. The problem is that steppers tend to cog very significantly. They're great for positioning things when you don't have any feedback - you know you get X amount of angle per step so you just count steps to position the system. But tracking a groove seems like something where you'd definitely want the groove to set the position. If your step rate is off, you're going to side load the stylus. Probably not good.

Comment: Actually, let me put it this way - imagine someone bumping the tone are several dozen times a second. That's what a stepper will introduce into your system.

Comment: JustJeff makes a very good point, the tone arm waves about a fair bit under normal operation (because no record is perfectly concentric, round, flat) so constraining it mechanically is asking for trouble. Steppers will probably introduce "cogging" noise, and avoiding that by micro-stepping will probably result in PWM noise or similar. The suggestion of gearing it to the turntable is beautifully elegant as 1 revolution means the needle must have tracked over by 1 groove.

Comment: Gearing the arm position to the turntable assumes that the groove pitch is the same and very finely controlled for all records - which it isn't. Perhaps you could use the difference between the arm angle and 90° as an error signal in a feedback loop with a dc motor.

Comment: I too think that a stepper is not a good choice for controlling a tone-arm. For tracking, perhaps one or more reflective object sensors could provide the necessary feedback (perhaps the type that focus around 1/8"), although the resolution of the grooves might be a bit fine for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want a VCO, you can try this super-easy circuit:

[image]

Since you want a very wide range of VCO frequency, use a 2N7000 rather than the BJT and increase C to around 0.27uF assuming 5V supply. Values will be a bit different if you use another type of op-amp and a lot different if you use a different supply voltage.

That should give you 0.2 ~ 27Hz for control voltage in the 0 ~ 5V range.

That said, I don't know if I'd let a stepper anywhere near a turntable, even with very rigid construction and microstepping.